# We are reminding you.. vs We remind you

Tags: formality, email

assuming I'm writing an email to remind about the scheduled activity that will start in one hour, which start for the email is correct:

1. We remind you that the scheduled activity starts in one hour.
2. We are reminding you that the scheduled activity starts in one hour.

P.S. I find "we would like to remind you" and "let us remind you" to be better in general, but I want to know which one of those two seems more correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**We remind you...** is rather stiff and wooden, almost hostile or at least an unfriendly warning of some kind.  **We're reminding you...** is not as stiff and off-putting but it's a tad unidiomatic. **We're writing to remind you...** or **This email is to remind you that ...** would be more idiomatic.